# How to give hyperlink to GIF image in CS5?

Tags: hyperlink, flash-cs5, photoshop

Hi i created a GIF image. Also i have given the hyperlink using photoshop. While seeing the preview the hyperlink is working. After saved and when i see in browser hyperlink is not working. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hyperlink from photoshop does not work. you've to do html coding.
create a simple text file in any text editor, and save it with TEST.html
(.html extension is to identify the html file by web browsers)

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
    <img src="http://www.exapmle.com/yourImage.gif" />
</a>
```

Use above format to link your gif to the desired location(I've used google.com for sample).